# I stay the stage of rebase in progress when I merge a suit of commit to the branch dev

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, rebase

Environment: Gitlab

Time: Merge my branch to branch dev.

Problem: I stay the rebase stage when I merge my branch to branch dev. It used `--no-ff` merge. The code has been displayed in `dev` branch, but we cannot finish the merge request anyway. I'm waiting for it about half an hour.

[image]

This is my first question on stackoverflow, if you have any suggestion for me, thanks a lot.

Comment: If I understand correctly : you ran `git merge --no-ff branch` on your machine, and pushed the updated `dev` branch to gitlab ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before merging your branch directly from GitLab, you must perform a rebase locally on your PC.

```
git checkout myBranch
git rebase dev
git push --force
```

Then you can re-try your merge on GitLab side: it will be a fast-forward one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm trying. Thanks!